# How to make a html form stack

Tags: html, css

UPDATE: This is how it looks now:
[New layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLB0n.png)

This is the html/css for the form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="/join/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

    <div style="text-align:center">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tick">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <style>

      form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #d2dce1;
        padding: 4vh 3vh;
      }





    body, .button, .tick {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
    }
    
    .button {
      width: 300px;
      height: 80px;
      background: rgba(221, 68, 68, 0.867)0;
      border-radius: 6px;
      transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.17, 0.40, 0.83);
    }
    
    .button svg {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      transition: all .5s;
    }
    
    .button__circle {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      background: rgba(221, 68, 68, 0.867);
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .tick {
      color: white;
      font-size: 2em;
      transition: all .9s;
    }
    </style>
    
    <script>
    let button = document.querySelector('.button');
    let buttonText = document.querySelector('.tick');
    
    const tickMark = "<svg width=\"58\" height=\"45\" viewBox=\"0 0 58 45\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><path fill=\"#fff\" fill-rule=\"nonzero\" d=\"M19.11 44.64L.27 25.81l5.66-5.66 13.18 13.18L52.07.38l5.65 5.65\"/></svg>";
    
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Submit";
    
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
      if (buttonText.innerHTML !== "Submit") {
        buttonText.innerHTML = "Submit";
      } else if (buttonText.innerHTML === "Submit") {
        buttonText.innerHTML = tickMark;
      }
      this.classList.toggle('button__circle');
    });
    
    </script>


</div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I want to have these fields and the button stacked one on top of the other, like 5 high and 1 wide. How do I do that? I can't find anything online. Even when I align them to center they just kinda jumble each other together, but I want them to stack one on top of the other neatly.

UPDATE: I followed the answer I checked below, now the text fields are lined up but the button is still to the left. How do I fix the button?

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS rather than simply a picture of it

Answer (score 1):

Add these to the `form`
Also take a look at [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #d2dce1;
  padding: 4vh 3vh;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="a">a</label>
  <input id="a" type="text" />
  <label for="a">a</label>
  <input id="a" type="text" />
  <label for="a">a</label>
  <input id="a" type="text" />
  <label for="a">a</label>
  <input id="a" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! the button didn't align to center though, how do I have the button align, too?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "form" element like  and Inside the form element, several inputs are nested with different type. also you should use css to give style to form element.

you can read this article in w3school website:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

and this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Styling_web_forms

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show some example and include some explaination from given links ?